# How to map C# enum to PostgreSQL enum using Dapper.FastCRUD?

Tags: c#, postgresql, enums, dapper, dapper-fastcrud

I have a class `Sample`, one of whose properties is an enum, `TargetType`. I have a corresponding table `samples` defined in a PostgreSQL database, along with a matching enum type, `targettypes`.

With Dapper.FastCRUD, I can retrieve records from the table successfully. However, I get an error during insertion:

```
Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42804: column "target_type" is of type targettype but expression is of type integer
```

**EDIT 1:** MoonStorm - creator of Dapper.FastCRUD - clarified that DB-CLR type conversions are handled by Dapper. So, now the question is:

**How do I tell Dapper to map the C# `enum TargetType` to PostgreSQL `ENUM TYPE targettype`?**

The enum is defined as:

```
public enum TargetType
{
    [NpgsqlTypes.PgName("Unknown")]
    UNKNOWN = 0,

    [NpgsqlTypes.PgName("Animal")]
    ANIMAL = 1,

    [NpgsqlTypes.PgName("Car")]
    CAR = 2,

    [NpgsqlTypes.PgName("Truck")]
    TRUCK = 3
}
```

And the class is defined as:

```
[Table("samples")]
public partial class Sample
{
    [Column("recording_time")]
    public DateTime RecordingTime { get; set; }

    [Column("x_position")]
    public double X_Position { get; set; }

    [Column("x_velocity")]
    public double X_Velocity { get; set; }

    [Column("y_position")]
    public double Y_Position { get; set; }

    [Column("y_velocity")]
    public double Y_Velocity { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public ulong Id { get; set; }

    [Column("target_type")] // <--- This is the offending column
    public TargetType TargetType { get; set; }

}
```

**EDIT 2**: Revised the example with working insert.

Illustration of usage:

```
using Npgsql;
using Dapper.FastCrud;
...

NpgsqlConnection.MapEnumGlobally<TargetType>("public.targettype"); // ... (1)

OrmConfiguration.DefaultDialect = SqlDialect.PostgreSql;

(using NpgsqlConnection conn = ...) // Connect to database
{
    var samples = conn.Find<Sample>();  // <--- This works correctly
    foreach (Sample s in samples)
        Console.WriteLine(s);

    ... // Generate new samples

    using (var writer = conn.BeginBinaryImport(sql))
    {
        foreach (Sample s in entities)
        {
            writer.StartRow();

            writer.Write(s.TargetType);  // <--- This insert works, due to (1)
            ...
        }
    }

    foreach (Sample sample in sampleList)
        conn.Insert<Sample>(sample);    // <--- This throws PostgresException
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've been faced with this same problem today, and my conclusion is that Dapper currently simply doesn't support this.  What you'd want to do is register a custom type handler with `SqlMapper` like this:

```
public class DbClass
{
  static DbClass()
  {
    SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler(new MyPostgresEnumTypeHandler());
  }

  class MyPostgresEnumTypeHandler : SqlMapper.TypeHandler<MyPostgresEnum>
  {
    public override MyPostgresEnum Parse(object value)
    {
      switch (value)
      {
        case int i: return (MyPostgresEnum)i;
        case string s: return (MyPostgresEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyPostgresEnum),s);
        default: throw new NotSupportedException($"{value} not a valid MyPostgresEnum value");
      }
    }

    public override void SetValue(IDbDataParameter parameter, MyPostgresEnum value)
    {
      parameter.DbType = (DbType)NpgsqlDbType.Unknown;
      // assuming the enum case names match the ones defined in Postgres
      parameter.Value = Enum.GetName(typeof(MyPostgresEnum), (int)value).ToString().ToLowerInvariant(); 
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work because Dapper ignores custom type handlers for Enums, specifically.  See https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/issues/259 for details.

My approach while waiting to see if this issue is ever dealt with is going to be to write `NpgsqlCommand` queries directly when dealing with these kinds of enums.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to convert TargetType to a integer.

Untested but something like:

```
Get 
{
    return (int)this.TargetType;
}
```

Comment: I think it's the converse problem. The error message suggests that Npgsql sees an `integer` whereas it expects a `targettype`. The enum `targettype` is defined in the postgres database. I feel I need to inform Dapper/Npgsql that `sample.TargetType` is of type `targettype`. Does that make sense?

Comment: http://www.npgsql.org/doc/enums_and_composites.html
NpgsqlConnection.MapEnumGlobally<TargetType>();

However take a look at dapper contrib, if you can use postgre without annoying mapping (possible on sql server).