# Npgsql enum mapping

Tags: c#, .net, dapper, npgsql, dapper-contrib

I'm using Dapper 2.0.123, Dapper.Contrib 2.0.78 and Npgsql 6.0.4 in ASP.Net API (.Net 6) project. Table in Postgres database has column `status` defined as `campaigns_status_enum`. Class and its enum looks like this:

```
[Table("campaigns")]
public class Campaign
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    // ommited, irrelevant to this question

    //[NpgsqlTypes.PgName("campaigns_status_enum")]
    public ECampaignStatus status { get; set; }

    public enum ECampaignStatus
    {
        [NpgsqlTypes.PgName("active")]
        active,
        [NpgsqlTypes.PgName("inactive")]
        inactive,
        [NpgsqlTypes.PgName("draft")]
        draft
    }
}
```

Enum in database is defined like this:

```
CREATE TYPE public.campaigns_status_enum AS ENUM
('active', 'inactive', 'draft');
```

In other questions here and in Npgsql [documentation](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/enums_and_composites.html) I've read that I need to use `NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper` and according to that, in my `Startup.cs` I've set the mapping like this:

```
NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.MapEnum<Common.Campaigns.Campaign.ECampaignStatus>("campaigns_status_enum");
```

inside `ConfigureServices`, before injecting `DatabaseService` which handles connection etc. I've also set

```
IDbConnection db = new NpgsqlConnection(ConnectionString);
if (db.State != ConnectionState.Open)
{
        db.Open();
        ((NpgsqlConnection)db).ReloadTypes();
}
```

inside this `DatabaseService` but apparently it has no effect. When I try to `INSERT` or `UPDATE` that table using Dapper.Contrib functions `UpdateAsync, InsertAsync`, I get following exception:

```
{"42804: column \"status\" is of type campaigns_status_enum but expression is of type integer\r\n\r\nPOSITION: 172"}
```

What I'm doing wrong, why this .Net enum isn't mapped to Postgres enum?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's worth it. i would keep it simple

without postgres enums any additional mappings c# enum would be mapped to integer. your entity has enum property and it maps to simple number in database

Comment: Unfortunately, we have to use it and we cannot change database fields.

Comment: i used postgres enums with EF and it worked just like you configured it, but...maybe Dapper.Contrib just does not support enums and converts them into intergers and you get such exception. for example, another simmilar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39880743/how-to-map-c-sharp-enum-to-postgresql-enum-using-dapper-fastcrud